# Discord Text channel creation

Tags: discord

I'm not sure about the code to create a text channel
I want it to be a command like create and then it would create 3 channels at the same time and then a message saying success.
I'm just not sure on the code to create a text channel and implement it so that when I do create it would make 3 pre-registered channels. Where I don't have to say create channel 1, channel 2, and so on. Just say create and it will create 3 channels that I have put the names from the code. Also, this is discord.py

Answer (score 1):

Add this into the command:

```py
for name in channel_names:
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name)
```

Comment: I mean like create a list [] and in that list would be text channels names, and when I do a command it will create all the text channels from that list.

Comment: Oh, alright. I edited it.